# Is $\ (x-x^7)\ $ factorable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way that I can factor $\ (x-x^7)\ $ so that I can cancle out a x-1 in a denominator?

Comment: Denominator?${}$

Comment: Use long division. As if you use the remainder theorem you can clearly see that $x=1$ is a factor of the numerator.

Comment: @GitGud I believe OP is trying to simplify an expression like $$\frac{x-x^7}{(x-1)P(x)}$$ and wants to cancel the $x-1$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

$$x-x^7 = x(1-x^6)$$

What do you get when you successively apply $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and $a^3 \pm b^3 = (a\pm b)(a^2\mp ab + b^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

You know since $x = 1$ is a root of $x - x^7$, $x - 1$ is a factor of that polynomial. Now,
$$x - x^7 = x(1 - x^6) = x(1 + x^3)(1 - x^3).$$
The only factor that evaluates to $0$ at $x = 1$ is the last one, so $x - 1$ must be a factor of that. You can use polynomial long division (which isn't so long given that the dividend has degree $3$) to show the often useful factorization
$$1 - x^3 = (1 - x)(1 + x + x^2).$$